# Return a date from a MySQL query to PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I think this is something simple. I have a table with a date column (due_date) in a MySQL database that I'm trying to get to PHP. I just need to return a Month/Date/Year in some fashion but this, and many variants, return nothing for that column. What am I missing?

```
function get_tasks(){
    $con = get_connection();
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT task_id, task_name, description, DATE_FORMAT(due_date,\"%M %d %Y\") AS task_date, priority, cat_name, status_desc FROM task LEFT JOIN category ON task.category_id = category.category_id INNER JOIN status ON task.status_id = status.status_id ORDER BY priority, due_date; ");
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $temp = array();
        array_push($temp, $row['task_id']);
        array_push($temp, $row['task_name']);
        array_push($temp, $row['description']);
        array_push($temp, $row['task_date']);
        array_push($temp, $row['priority']);
        array_push($temp, $row['cat_name']);
        array_push($temp, $row['status_desc']);
        array_push($data, $temp);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    return $data;
}
```

Here are screenshots of the page I'm starting (pardon the less than stellar visuals) and the return from the db when executing the query.

[Image of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD5hS.png)
[Image of the db return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSkBH.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your date_format like below:

```
DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%M %d %Y")
```

> Read detail documentation for [DATE_FORMAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-date_format-function.php) to understand how to display different date formats

So your final query looks like:

```
SELECT task_id,
       task_name,
       description,
       DATE_FORMAT(due_date, "%M %d %Y") AS task_date,
       priority,
       cat_name,
       status_desc
FROM task
LEFT JOIN category ON task.category_id = category.category_id
INNER JOIN status ON task.status_id = status.status_id
ORDER BY priority,
         due_date;
```

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. Since the query is enclosed in quotes this doesn't work. I tried various things, single quotes, backticks, \"%M %d %Y\" etc. That;s really the crux of the problem.

Comment: The query runs as is in MySQL and gives results.  I also tried:     $thing = 'DATE_FORMAT(due_date, "%d %m %Y") AS task_date';
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT task_id, task_name, description, " . $thing . " , priority, [etc]

Comment: @JJRyan What error are you getting? I have tried the date_format in another database and it works fine.

Comment: No errors on the last few attempts. The column just doesn't return anything.

Comment: @JJRyan Can you share the screenshot of the response you are getting?

Comment: Images attached to the original post. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Oh-- the page image is from earlier. That's why the results of the query are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Good heavens. I said it was something simple. This is really embarrassing but the problem was 1 line of code in the front end. This part was probably always working. Fixed now. Thanks for your time.